# Navigation stack, rosparam error! [help!]

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I have set up the navigation stack. And after running:

```
roslaunch navigation_for_segbot move_base.launch
```

I receive the following error msg:

```
error loading <rosparam> tag: 

    file does not exist [/home/abc/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/navigation_for_segbot/params/costmap_common_params.yaml]
XML is <rosparam command="load" file="$(find navigation_for_segbot)/params/costmap_common_params.yaml" ns="global_costmap"/>
```

Here is my roslaunch file:

```
<launch>
  <master auto="start"/>

  <!-- Run the map server -->
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find navigation_for_segbot)/maps/bwi_test_world.yaml"/>

  <!--- Run AMCL -->
  <include file="$(find amcl)/examples/amcl_omni.launch" />

  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find navigation_for_segbot)/params/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find navigation_for_segbot)/params/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />
    <rosparam file="$(find navigation_for_segbot)/params/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find navigation_for_segbot)/params/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />
    <rosparam file="$(find navigation_for_segbot)/params/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>
</launch>
```

And I have do have my

```
costmap_common_params.yaml
```

inside my `params` folder inside the packge.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64615/navigation-stack,-rosparam-error!-%5Bhelp!%5D/) by [Gazer](https://answers.ros.org/users/4846/gazer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2013-06-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-06-10**:
Are you 100% sure that the file /home/abc/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/navigation_for_segbot/params/costmap_common_params.yaml exists, that it's readable by your user and that it contains some yaml code?

**Comment by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on 2013-08-01**:
did u solve this??? that thing is happening to me....

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2013-08-02**:
The error says exactly what the problem is. The file does not exist.

**Comment by [salime](https://answers.ros.org/users/5267/salime/) on 2013-08-02**:
I have that file, I am completely sure, and the code is readable because it was in the tutorial, so I don't know what else could it be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I experienced the same error with a different package. I could open the file and its in the right location too.

The solution is just delete the file and create it once again and put the data in it. It worked for me!

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2014-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0